# Использование модели контроллера администратора в пользовательской части

Tags: php, opencart

Есть задача по импорту данных в opencart. Реализация довольно нестандартная. Но вот хочется использовать стандартные функции по добавлению данных.
Как должно работать, по POST запросу на определённый адрес (это реализовано), в определённом каталоге распаковывается файл архива, содержащий XML (это реализовано). Далее xml парсится (реализовано частично), и полученные данные должна обработать модель. Понятное дело, что в пользовательской части модель не содержит необходимые функции, которые имеются в модели администратора, по этому в модель пользовательского модуля скопированы функции из модели администратора (из модели категорий - /admin/model/catalog/category.php).
При отправке $data массива распарсенных данных, есть проблема (просто не могу понять) от куда в модель попадает значение language_id и как вообще его туда передать?

```
foreach ($data['category_description'] as $language_id => $value) {
  $this->db->query("
    INSERT INTO 
      " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description 
    SET 
      category_id = '" . (int)$category_id . "', 
      language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "', 
      name = '" . $this->db->escape($value['name']) . "', 
      description = '" . $this->db->escape($value['description']) . "',
      meta_title = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_title']) . "',
      meta_description = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_description']) . "',
      meta_keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_keyword']) . "'"
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в общем задача имела в корне неверную идею. В случае возникновения схожей идеи, пишите свой контроллер и модель для каталога.